# TLD specific 301 rewrite for relaunch on new server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

the company I work for is relaunching their newly built website on a new server under the same domain as before.

Example:
www.website.com/company/info/news.html on server A is going to change to www.website.com/news on server B.
On server A there is a second website (mostly a clone, so the same links are used) under a different TLD (website.ca). So there exists also a www.website.ca/company/info/news which should not be redirected.

We are relaunching only website.com for now so I need TLD-specific redirects. Everything combined there are about 250 pages that need redirecting to the new equivalent.
Those redirects are mainly aimed at crawlers and bots so we do not lose our pagerank and also for visitors with bookmarks, so I will add the rewrite-rules to the .htaccess-file on both servers.

I'm having trouble finding examples for this very specific scenario, so this is what I got so far from various how-tos and tutorials:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.website.com/company/info/news.html$ [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/news [L,R=301]
```

From what I understand it should redirect http://www.website.com/company/info/news.html to http://www.website.com/news with the information that it is a 301 and case-insensitive matching for the URL I want to redirect.

If this is correct I will add 250 RewriteCond (1 for each "old" page) and 1 RewriteRule per "new" page (about 10 in total) in this style:

```
RewriteCond 1
RewriteCond 2
RewriteRule 1
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Your Cond/Rule is wrong, but to find the correct one you need to be more precise (you have two different examples that do not follow the same pattern)

Comment: I changed the example and the rule to match - what's wrong with the Cond/Rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking for domain name, it is correct to look into %{HTTP_HOST}, but since it contains only the domain name (without the [REQUEST_SCHEME](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) or [REQUEST_URI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)) you should compare it to www.website.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
```

For your exact example, the .htaccess RewriteRule would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^company/info/news.html$ /news [L,R=301]
```

But such exact rules would require you to write new Cond/Rule pait for every single .html file. If your structure follows some pattern, maybe something like this would work:

```
RewriteRule ^company/info/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

That should rewrite 
http://www.website.com/company/info/anything.html to 
http://www.website.com/anything